# The meaning of "Yo, Pops"

Tags: meaning, american-english, slang

In the movie "Equalizer" (2014), the co-worker addressed Denzel Washington, "Yo, Pops, bet you didn't have to push dollies at your old job." and Denzel Washington replied, "Guilty as charged."
I just don't understand the meaning of "Yo, Pops" and why past tense "did" was used. Can anybody help, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Yo, Pops" is a possibly insulting slang phrase that means "Hello, old man".

"Yo" is a slang term to get someone's attention.  It has connotations of either "friendly enough that it is OK to be rude", or "rude".

"Pops" is a slang term for "Pa" or "Father" or "old man".

The sentence is in the past tense because it is asking about something that happened in the past -- what Washington's character did in his previous job.

Comment: In this context, should it be "pop" instead?

Comment: *Pops* is what the man said, so *pops* it is. What I mean is that *pops* as a singular noun for 'old man' is standard in some dialects of English. *Pop* is an informal term for 'father' used by most AmE speakers.